# Why is Mathematica returning Abs[-1+x] even with assumption x<1?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

With the following `Simplify[Abs[-1 + x], {-1 + x < 0}]`, I expect *Mathematica* to return `1-x`, but it instead gives the same `Abs[-1+x]` back. Why is it so?

Comment: Try `PowerExpand` or `PiecewiseExpand`.

Comment: `Assuming[-1 + x < 0, Abs[-1 + x] // ComplexExpand // Simplify]`

Answer (score 11):

Probably because the simplification you are looking for would result in a "larger" expression.

Examples:

```
In[1]:= Simplify[Abs[x], x > 0]
Out[1]= x

In[2]:= Simplify[Abs[x], x < 0]
Out[2]= Abs[x]

In[3]:= Simplify[-Abs[x], x < 0]
Out[3]= x
```

For `Out[2]`, you probably expect `-x`. This is actually represented as `Times[-1, x]`, which is more "complex" than `Abs[x]` according to the complexity measure used by `Simplify`. The complexity measure is based mostly on [`LeafCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html).

---

There is an entire section dedicated to *this very example* in the documentation of [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html), under Options -> ComplexityFunction. Please check it for more information, and for an alternative complexity function that leads to the result you wanted.

Comment: Yet, `Simplify[Times[-1,x],x<0]` does not return `Abs[x]` even though the latter has `LeafCount` 2 and the former has 3. ;)

Comment: Yes, it probably does not ever try that transformation. We need two things to let simplification happen: (1) try that particular transformation (2) decide that the result is simpler than the starting point.

Comment: Why is `-x` interpreted as `Times[-1,x]` and not `Minus[x]`?

Comment: @polfosol `x/4` is also interpreted as `Times[1/4, x]` and not as `Divide[x, 4]`. I don't _know_ the reason, but my _assumption_ has always been that this is done for canonicalization, i.e. for bringing expressions into a common, easily interpretable form. Consider this polynomial: `x^3/3 - 2x^2 + 5x - 9`. Look at the `FullForm`. It has the same structure regardless of whether coefficients are positive or negative and regardless of whether that have the form `1/a` or `a`. This is very convenient for extracting coefficients. This is just one example of the advantages of canonicalization.

Comment: @polfosol The more usual use of canonicalization is to make it easy to compare expressions, i.e. `Minus[x, 1]` and `Plus[x, -1]` are mathematically equivalent, but formally different. It is useful to bring them to the same form because detecting that they are the same becomes trivial.